# What is the meaning of this warning during war compile using maven?

Tags: java, maven, jetty, cometd, maven-war-plugin

I am overriding the toJSON and fromJSON methods of JSON.Convertor for a Cometd/Jetty application for handling JSON to Java Objects and visa versa.  I am getting this warning during compilation, but it doesn't seem to effect the code since it works, but would like to get to the bottom of it.  Here's the output when I compile:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) @ rt ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 15 source files to /opt/rt_deploy/jetty_test_8080/build/rt/target/classes
[WARNING] Models.java:[98,32] found raw type: java.util.Map missing type arguments for generic class java.util.Map<K,V>
```

That warning is pointing to the fromJSON method in the JSON.Convertor class I am extending:

```
public static class RtUserConvertor implements JSON.Convertor {
    @Override
    public void toJSON(Object obj, JSON.Output out) {
        RtUser rtUser = (RtUser) obj;

        out.addClass(RtUser.class);
        out.add("duid", rtUser.getDuid());
        out.add("username", rtUser.getUsername());
        out.add("gender", rtUser.getGender());
        out.add("age", rtUser.getAge());
        out.add("location", rtUser.getLocation());
        out.add("pic_url", rtUser.getPic_url());
    }

    @Override
    public Object fromJSON(Map object) {
        long duid = Long.valueOf(object.get("duid").toString());
        String username = (String) object.get("username");
        String gender = (String) object.get("gender");
        int age = Integer.valueOf(object.get("age").toString());
        String location = (String) object.get("location");
        String pic_url = (String) object.get("pic_url");

        return new RtUser(duid, username, gender, age, location, pic_url);
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem to like it if I override with anything other than having the "object" param as a normal Map.  Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Should have mentioned that the JSON class is from org.eclipse.jetty.util.ajax.JSON;

Comment: Your `fromJSON` method has a parameter of the raw type `Map`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis :  obviously

Answer (score 0):

```
public Object fromJSON(Map object) {
```

Here generics are not used to define what type of objects the `Map` can contain. For example, if `object` would be defined as `Map<String, Integer>` only a map with these type arguments would be allowed to be passed to the method.

It is possible to pass any map to your method, a `Map<String, Integer>`, a `Map<String, Long>`, etc.

I suspect you are implementing [this](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/util/ajax/JSON.Convertor.html) interface. Since that interface does not have this generic functionality, I guess there is not too much you can do to get rid of the warning except isolating the warning to a single place in the code.

And as you say, it won't affect the functionality of your code. As long as your casts to `String` and parsing to `Long`/`Integer` works. This is what generics is about, letting you know what type of objects that exists in the collection, which in turn lets you avoid ugly casting.

Comment: That is indeed the interface I am implementing.  The code works as expected, but Java not being my primary language, I figured that I could be implementing it incorrectly, or not in the best way.  Thanks for your input!